# Nginx Load Balancer with Autoscaled virtual machines

Tags: azure, nginx, load-balancing

I have got few virtual machines in azure which gets autoscaled. I want to use a nginx load balancer in front of these virtual machines. So Whenever a virtual machines gets added or removed I want these changes in my nginx load balancer. Is there any way I could achieve this?

Comment: I think the `NGINX Plus API` can do what you request, read more here: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/dynamic-configuration-api/

Comment: Nginx Plus API is only for Nginx plus I guess and I am using open source nginx load balancer.